# How can I get a decimal answer for this code?

Tags: java, android

`android:inputType="numberDecimal" = Ok`... 
The problem is i can't get an answer w/ decimal the app always crash.
What i'm trying to do is i'm trying to find which is the highest digit among the three numbers that i have entered.

```
if (one.getText().toString().length() == 0.0) {
        one.setError("Required!");
    } else if (two.getText().toString().length() == 0.0) {
        two.setError("Required!");
    } else if (three.getText().toString().length() == 0.0) {
        three.setError("Required!");
    } else {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(one.getText().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(two.getText().toString());
        int num3 = Integer.parseInt(three.getText().toString());
        if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) {
            output.setText("" + num1);
        } else if (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3) {
            output.setText("" + num2);
        } else
            output.setText("" + num3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Integers don't support decimals.

Comment: And `getText()` already returns a string. You don't need to call `toString()`.

Comment: @user207421 `EditText.getText()` returns `Editable` and cannot be cast to `String`. A string returned by `EditText.toString()` is not the one in the text box. so getText() is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange..!

Firstly, the `.length()` returns an **integer**. So, just use `== 0` instead of `== 0.0`.

Instead of comparing the length to `0`, I suggest comparing the string to `null`. Use `editText.getString().equals(null)` to get a `true` or `false`

Then, `Integer.parseInt()` returns an Integer and **not decimal values**. So, use `Double.parseDouble()` to get a return value of type **Double**

The `Integer.parseInt()` method is what is mainly responsible for the error as that **method looks only for whole numbers** in the string and on finding a `.` which is a character, gets confused..!

Remember, under the `EditText` in the Layout's XML file, you have to add the `inputType` attribute like this:

`android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

This attribute tells the keyboard on the target device that the input is a decimal number.

Hope this works..!

SDA

Comment: may be good to chang "returns " to "accept", I think.

Comment: Could you please mention on which line..?

Comment: The line Then, Integer.parseInt() returns an Integer and not decimal values. In some locale it's acceptable but passing params like "12.345" is the problem.

Comment: Yay, thanks! That Double.parseDouble() works!

Comment: I believe that is what I meant by those words

Comment: Um... What was the downvote for..?

Answer (score -2):

length() method of String class returns int 
(how can numbers of characters be decimal??)

I guess you are trying to write a code to compare 3 numbers to find the largest of them. And you are trying to check if 3 inputs are provided.

If this the case, then you can simply check args.length() = 3 (or > 2 and accepts first 3 inputs). And then try to convert it to int/float/double to compare.

And if inputs are decimals then use Double.parseDouble() or Float.parseFloat().

Comment: Integer.parseInt("1.23") is the problem.